Subprocess overhead vs library function?
I'm writing an application, and I want to perform hardware encoding (av1. My hardware is capable of that) of frames.
I seem to have two options - either call ffmpeg as a child process, or dynamically link ffmpeg/gstreamer and call the library functions directly. The child process option will be significantly easier.
In my mind, spawning ffmpeg as a child process carries much more overhead compared to calling the library functions. Am I correct? If so, is the overhead just in RAM, or will it also affect performance?
(It's for livestreaming so the encoding is continuous)

Most overhead will come from encoding the video, so the overhead of spawning ffmpeg process is likely negligible, perhaps unless you have a lot of short videos.

The actual advantages imo is more the management; passing data and errors back and forth might be easier with direct calls. Interacting with subprocesses sounds simpler on paper, but using a library has a good chance of being easier in the long run, after some initial effort to set it up.
